# Android Studio: XML File (design tab) can't adjust size or position of TextView

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio Version: 2.2.3

Goal: Adjust size of TextView Component in an `XML` file through the design tab.

What I'm doing: Dragging the "TextView" Component in the Widgets folder from the sidebar while in the design tab of the XML file. Then I grab one of the 8 little boxes and attempt to stretch it (like most programs in the world).

Expected Output: I expect the "TextView" Component to become the new size that is outlined when I stretch the Component.

What is happening: Origin of TextView goes right on the origin of the parent object (content_main) and does not change size.

I can change the size manually in the Text tab of the XML file. That being said, I assume there's something wrong with android:layout_width and height = wrap_content. If I change this to whatever px I want, I get the expected output. What can I do so I can modify the size in the design tab?

[EDIT] this applies to everything I put into the the container.xml design tab (buttons, text, inputs...)

Content.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#006699"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.brandonwillis.myapplication.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.brandonwillis.myapplication.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:minHeight="151dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

<include layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:visibility="visible" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Video of what I'm doing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NEtkrlnV6o

Side question (that I can probably find somewhere else), how can I format my code correctly on StackOverflow? It clearly loses its indentation. I hit the code brackets and just paste in my code.

Comment: It sounds like you are pulling the Constraints instead of the scale buttons.  The constraint buttons are on the flat faces of the view, and to scale you will want to grab just the corners of your `TextView`.

Comment: Very new to Android Development (Day 1), so what are these constraints and scale buttons? Also, I don't know what you mean by "flat faces of the view". Also, if I grab just the corners it snaps to the origin so something else must be wrong. I'll be researching what these things mean in the meantime. Thanks

Comment: Why was this questions down-voted? I asked the question in the most elaborate way possible and posted a video along with it. I think I'm done with this site.

Comment: `ConstraintView` is a new `ViewGroup` that lets you set 'anchor' like constraints to views.  Can you see if your main `ViewGroup` is a constraint or something like a `RelativeLayout` instead?

Comment: It says RelativeLayout

Comment: I find it strange that I can reposition these widgets without a problem, but I can't resize them.

Comment: I understand that I have layout_width and layout_height set to wrap_content which I know is what is restricting me, but even if I set layout_width and layout_height to values such as 80dp or 720px, I cannot resize it.

Comment: What happens when you try to manually resize it?  It just stays the same?

Comment: If I type in the new size, it works. But, if I try to do it in the design tab by dragging the dots out, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Content.xml file change RelativeLayout to Absolute layout..

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you explain the difference between these layouts?

Answer (score 0):

In your `TextView`, try removing `alignparent start and top` and then try setting the `height` and `width` to `20dp`, then scale it again in the design see if it works.

Comment: No luck. It does the same exact thing.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: You can't do that because of `wrap_content`

**Long answer**
Initially, know about what is wrap_content. wrap_content automatically allocates height and width of the View. if your textview has 50 words or however it dynamically assigns height and width of the View. you are trying to manually change the height and width by pulling it, you can't do that. better you can set height and width manually by.

```
<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="200dp" <!-- Your Size here -->
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
     />
```

Comment: I have this set up and it still does the same thing. At this point, I think I'm just going to work out of the 'text' tab instead of the design tab. I never like DnD anyways.

Comment: no otherway, you have to use "text" tab to customize the textview properties... If you learn how to design using text tab., you will never use design tab for placing a widget...

Comment: @BrandonWillis if you want to make textview size static, say 200dp(width)x 48dp(height), you have to mention in the layout_width and layout_height properties in xml layout.